# Installing Windows 2012 KVM Guest on Ubuntu 14.10 - unable to VNC into guest

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, vnc

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 (x64) host, and I am using KVM to setup a Windows 2012 R2 guest VM on it.

I am using the `virt-install` command to set things up.

I have setup a bridge network in `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports    eth0
    bridge_stp      off
    bridge_maxwait  0
    bridge_fd       0
```

My `virt-install` command-line is:

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system --arch=x86_64 -n win2012 --ram 4096 --cpu host --vcpus=2 --hvm --disk size=80,sparse=false,format=raw,bus=virtio -
-cdrom /srv/sunix/en_windows_server_2012_r2_with_update_x64_dvd_6052708.iso --os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k8 --network bridge=br0,model=virtio --noautoconsole

Starting install...
Allocating 'win2012-1.img'                                                                                                                                    |  80 GB     00:00
Creating domain...                                                                                                                                            |    0 B     00:01
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting  for installation to complete.
```

It seems to be waiting at that point for quite some time. I thought of using vnc to connect to the box to see what's going on.

Even though I've used `--noautoconsole`, my understanding is that the VNC display should still get created by default. However, this is the output of `vncdisplay`:

```
virsh vncdisplay win2012
error: Failed to get VNC port. Is this domain using VNC?
```

This is the output of `domiflist`:

```
virsh domiflist win2012
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
vnet0      bridge     br0        virtio      52:54:00:1d:dd:ab
```

However, according to my local DHCP server, that device hasn't tried to claim a DHCP lease yet.

I am thinking this might be because of the `virtio` network drive I've selected, and that Windows 2012 R2 doesn't support it out of the box.

However, is there any way to still connect to the box?

Also, are there any issues you can see in the way I'm setting up this guest?

Comment: I'd use the graphical mode, create the guest using virt-manager and follow the setup through in a graphical console directly. virt-install  has it's issues

Answer (score 1):

I would *explicitly* specify `--graphics vnc` here, just to be sure. And be sure to change it to SPICE when you install the SPICE guest tools.

Also, you chose Windows 2008 as the OS you're installing. Why not 2012 R2? `--os-variant win2k12r2`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 sorts of VM VNC,

- VNC provided by hypervisor (aka. qemu).
- And VNC provided by the VM self.

Obviously , libvirt and qemu have no idea of 'VNC provided by the VM self',
the cmd 'virsh vncdisplay' actually extract vnc bind info from 'VNC provided by hypervisor',
while your virt-install cmd line didn't instruct libvirt to do so.

So, your case is irrevalant with guest network info,
and  @Michael Hampton is right , you should specify 'vnc bind info' while you builing the VM.

If you want to keep your current VM but need to append 'vnc bind info' to it,
here it is:

EDITOR=vim virsh edit ${your domain}
and a section like this:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='en-us'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```

then shutoff the vm and start it again.
You will be able to 'virsh vncdisplay' then , I hope. :)